# dont let the user select a value in combobox in a DataGridView that already has been select

Tags: c#, winforms, enums, combobox

I have i datagridview with 3 column:
Motor| TextBox | TextBox

my combobox has some Enums values which the user can select from.

and the user cant allow to select 1 values from my Enums more than 1 time..

hope maked my question clear enough:D

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; i++)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value == e.FormattedValue)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Value already selected");
                    e.Cancel = true;
                }                
            }

        }
```

dont seem to work like i would have it to

Answer (score 0):

See  `CellValidating` and `CellEndEdit` events in datagridview. With them you can put some validating logic into the grid's cell and, for example, prevent some action on cell with `e.Cancel = true;`
To see which enum values are already selected you can add new member `List<int> selectedItems` and check if e.Value(in the cell validation event handler) is in that list. If it already IS- call `e.Cancel = true` and add some validation text, if its not-add it to `selecterItems` list.

Hope understood you properly and that will help. 
You can see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykdxa0bc.aspx) article about cell validation too.

Comment: you can write something like this: `for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; i++)
{
     if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value == e.Value)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Value already selected");e.Cancel = true;
                }                
}`  in 'dataGridView1_CellValidating' event handler

Comment: Sorry, e.FormattedValue.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellvalidatingeventargs.formattedvalue.aspx

Comment: because else i will get a exception, because my datagridview i always adding a new row which i null...

Comment: Sure, but if you will edit-then last row wont be checked. Check row on null in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a more LINQish approach to reduce the explicit looping. And an invariant culture check to ensure that the values being selected take culture in to consideration ...

You could probably take the LINQ expressions a step further and hide them behind Extension methods for better readability as well.

But as for the question, in general, you definitely want to be in the **CellValidating** and the **CellEndEdit** events as state previously.

Here's some LINQish code:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(4);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Column1.Items.Add("Item 1");
        Column1.Items.Add("item 1");
        Column1.Items.Add("Item 3");
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataGrid = sender as DataGridView;
        if (dataGrid == null) return;

        var rowsWithComboValues = dataGrid.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(row => row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().First().Value != null);
        if (rowsWithComboValues.Any(row => string.Compare(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString(), e.FormattedValue.ToString(), true, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == 0))
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```